# How to get spell suggesstion for the word that cursor is on in the minibuffer?

Tags: latex, ispell

Example behavior:

When I am using `python-mode` if a cursor is on top of on a error, the error message is printed out on the minibuffer.

If I have following line `import o` , import keyword get bold and colored red. When I move cursor on top of it, `F401 'o' imported but unused` is showned on the minibuffer.

[image]

---

Can I have similiar behavior for wrongly typed words in LaTeX file?

Lets say I typed `lif`, `emacs` makes it bold and color in red since it is misspelled. When I move cursor on top of it, I want emacs to show automatically suggested words for correction in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Doesn't `flyspell-mode` do something close to this?

Comment: Actually yes but I have to press keybinding (ex: `alt-;`) to show suggestions when the cursor is on top of the word, please correct me if I am wrong. On my questoins I want suggestions to show up automatically if my cursor is on top of the word